# AFNetworking upload file

Tags: cocoa, rest, afnetworking

I am uploading files using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and [AFAmazonS3Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client) to Amazon S3. I loop over an array of files and all the files upload successfully to the S3 server as expected, but during upload extra content has been added to each file that should not be there. E.g. the added text to file named kmeans.sh looks like this:

```
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="kmeans.sh"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

This kind of content occurs at the top of each file. My method for uploading looks like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self 
                       multipartFormRequestWithMethod:method 
                                                 path:destination 
                                           parameters:parameters 
              constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data 
                                    name:@"file" 
                                fileName:[fileURL.path lastPathComponent] 
                                mimeType:self.mimetype];
    }];
```

What am I doing wrong here that adds extra info to my files? I am really at a loss to figure this one out and I appreciate any suggestions I can try.

**UPDATE:**
Originally I did as Matt suggested but I used the PUT method instead of POST. Today I downloaded latest version of AFAmazonS3Client and tried to upload files with both PUT and POST using the methods:

```
postObjectWithFile:(NSString *)path destinationPath:(NSString *)destinationPath parameters....
putObjectWithFile:(NSString *)path destinationPath:(NSString *)destinationPath parameters....
```

For the file "Lima1996.pdf" uploading to bucket objcs3 and prefix "Site3/hei/", the stringToSign looks like:
    POST

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Thu, 06 Jun 2013 00:37:04 GMT
/objcs3/Site3/hei/Lima1996.pdf
```

And the request looks like:

```
 auth: {
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, nb;q=0.9";
    Authorization = "removed";
    "Content-Length" = 915478;
    "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY";
    Date = "Thu, 06 Jun 2013 00:37:04 GMT";
    "User-Agent" = "connectCloudTest/1.0 (Mac OS X Version 10.8.4 (Build 12E55))";
  }
```

Everythng looks good, but when I upload the file using the POST method I keep getting error message

```
Upload failed Expected status code in (200-299), got 405 (-1011)
```

While using the PUT method results in the previous error where the upload succeeds but the content is garbled with the extra header information as in the original question. Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your help! Cheers, Trond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to successfully upload my files without any additional headers by replacing the `putObjectWithMethod` in [AFAmazonS3Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client) with:

```
 (void)putObjectWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                   file:(NSString *)filePath
        destinationPath:(NSString *)destinationPath
             parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
               progress:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))progress
                success:(void (^)(id responseObject))success
                failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *filerequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
    [filerequest setCachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:filerequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (data && response) {

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [super requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:destinationPath parameters:nil];
        [self authorizeRequest:request withPath:destinationPath];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (success) {
            success(responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];

       [requestOperation setUploadProgressBlock:progress];
       [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:requestOperation];
}
```

}

I dont know why my POST method never worked, but with PUT everything works well. Cheers, Trond

Comment: My posts don't work as well using AFAmazonS3Client, possibly because I'm using the sts service to generate temporary credentials, and I don't think posts are an allowed action when you set up the temporary credential policy.

Answer (score 0):

AFAmazonS3Client has methods like `postObjectWithFile:destinationPath:parameters:progress:success:failure:` which takes care of all of the multipart form building. Creating your own request should not be necessary, and may be the cause of the additional headers in your files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: As I read the Amazon S3 REST API spec they doesn't support multipart for it's PUT requests but only for POST requests. The AFAmazonS3Client currently assumes it's supported by both PUT and POST requests. See description for http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html vs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

The solution from @TrondKristiansen works very nicely for me.